# webpack export each function with relevant code in same file

Tags: webpack

**handler.js**

```
import moment from 'moment';


export const hello = () => {
  return {
    timestamp: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
    message: 'hello()'
  }
}
export const bye = () => {
  return {
    message: 'bye()'
  }
}
```

and when I build them, I'd like to see like that

`hello.js`, `bye.js`.

Only `hello.js` has `moment`, `bye.js` hasn't.

are there any options about this in webpack?

**edited**

I have a `javascript` file, and I am gonna separate it using `webpack`.

My `js` file is like above that.

What I want to get is

**hello.js**

```
var moment = require('moment');
exports.hello = function(){
  return {
    timestamp: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
    message: 'hello()'
  }
}
```

and

**bye.js**

```
exports.bye = function(){
  return {
    message: 'bye()'
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understood what is the issue, can you elaborate?

Comment: @felixmosh I added it